# c# Windows Forms: Событие при получении фокуса не работает

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, события, .net-5

У меня есть две формы: главная и форма авторизации, которая закрывается при успешном входе. Я хочу, чтобы при переводе фокуса на основную форму (после закрытия формы авторизации), выполнялся `GenerateControls()`, которая изменяет элементы формы.

Проблема – `onGotFocus()` **никогда** не срабатывает. Я ожидал, что это событие отвечает за получение фокуса, но оказалось, что это не так. Это очень раздражает, потому что событие буквально называется "при получении фокуса", а на деле не срабатывает, даже если альт-табнутся на эту форму. Какое же событие мне использовать? Или я должен что-то настроить перед тем, как использовать `override onGotFocus()` в своём коде?

Я пытался как-то вызывать onGotFocus() основной формы внутри `onClosed()`, но я вообще не понимаю, как передать основную форму внутрь метода формы авторизации. Да и, я думаю, это не самый верный способ решения проблемы.

(под получением фокуса я подразумеваю смену состояния окна на активное, когда шапка окна выделяется соответствующим цветом)

Post Scriptum.

Удаляя код до тех пор, пока он не заработает, я обнаружил, что проблема была в Form1.Designer.cs – когда я переношу в только что созданную форму без какого либо кода, то этот **автоматически сгенерированный код** заставляет `onGotFocus()` не работать. В чём же проблема? В кнопках и комбобоксах!!! `InitializeComponent()` между `this.SuspendLayout()` и `this.AutoScaleDimensions = //...` – событие фокуса до сих пор не работает. И только когда я закомментировал все кнопки и комбобоксы в начале `InitializeComponent()`, событие фокуса заработало. Попробовал взять тот же проект с двумя пустыми формами – фокус работает. Добавил кнопку (через конструктор) – фокус не работает. Я просто мозг взрывается, что за "гений" писал этот onGotFocus, что он ломается при добавлении кнопки. Вот скажите мне, как    `this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();` может сломать фокус?!! (это буквально тот кусок кода, который если закомментировать – всё работает – и это в новом проекте с двумя *пустыми* формами, на одной из которых добавлена кнопка (через конструктор))
Но это не важно, важно – **где мне взять нормальный `onGotFocus()`**??

Итак, вот ваш минимальный код для повторения ошибки – создать проект WindowsFroms, добавить форму, в первой форме прописать

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Form2().ShowDialog();
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }
```

Теперь, можете поставить точку останова в `onGotFocus` и наслаждаться тем, как добавление простой **кнопки** убивает вашу программу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: tym32167, сделано. Бесполезный совет, на самом деле. Если человек знает как GotFocus() на самом деле, то он ответит и без кода. Таким образом, принцип минимальности и самодостаточности был выполнен изначально

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что вы не понимаете до конца, что такое фокус. Пустая форма получает фокус, потому что в ней ничего нет. Форма с элементом управления на ней фокус не получает, так как в фокусе будет этот элемент управления. Вы кнопку поставили на форме, а вы заметили, что кнопка в фокусе находится, а не форма? И Tab не убирает фокус с кнопки, тк она все, что на форме есть.

Comment: Пишете, что минимальный пример бесполезен, но вы благодаря ему нашли корень проблемы, а мы без вашего примера не догадались бы о кнопке. Так что нечестно писать, что мой совет, который вам не стоил ничего, но стоил моего времени мне, вам не дал никакой пользы.

Comment: Информация о том, что добавление любой кнопки/групбокса или другого интерактивного элемента "ломает" GotFocus не даёт никакой полезной информации для решения проблемы – я ведь всё равно не смогу построить форму без интерактивных элементов – как до вашего совета, так и после, я был уверен в том, что GotFocus не работает как мне надо. Поэтому ваш совет бесполезен.

Comment: В тексте вопроса я указал, что я понимаю под фокусом, поэтому было бы гораздо полезнее, если бы вы сразу бы поправили моё определение, либо посоветовали бы другое событие, которое соответствует моему определению "фокуса", чем заставили бы **потратить моё время** на минимизацию примера. Так что, вы не правы – вам-то комментарий не стоил много времени (учитывая, что вы вряд ли читали вопрос), а вот мне пришлось потратить его на создание минимального примера, который *не принёс никаких результатов* для решения проблемы

Comment: Я не держу в памяти все значения всех событий формы от технологии, которую не использую. Все, что я вам написал, я понял потому что собрал ваш пример у себя, запустил и проверил. Потому мне и нужен был минимальный пример. Но я, пожалуй, не буду вас больше ни в чем убеждать, я понял вашу позицию по вопросу.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо тогда, возьму на заметку. Нигде выше я это не упоминал, поэтому напишу здесь – что под "бесполезным советом" я имел/имею ввиду "бесполезный для решения данной проблемы совет", поэтому не думайте, что я слишком обесцениваю ваш комментарий :)
Ну и всё же, вы же могли мне указать на неверное определение фокуса (в первом комментарии), почему этого не сделали?

Comment: потому что я тогда этого не знал, я занимаюсь микросервисами на java и не пишу на win формах уже лет 10 как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл альтернативу, которая подходит в данной ситуации – событие `Activated`, которое можно создать в конструкторе, нажав на значек ⚡ в свойствах формы (окна), нажав на пустое поле рядом с Activated два раза.